# A vague definition in a dictionary, "shag：a sexual partner of a specified ability". Is there any better or plainer explanation?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, offensive-language

I'm not a native English-reader, I'm Chinese. So mostly I get meanings of words by consulting dictionaries. I read this in a dictionary about the word *shag*:

> a sexual partner of a specified ability.

*Sexual partner* is quite understandable to me, but what does "of a specified ability" refer to?
Sexual ability?

Could there be any better explanation which would give me a plainer idea of it or are there words synonymous with *shag*?

Comment: I think that's trying to say that you would not generally just call somebody a _shag,_ but rather a _good shag_ or a _lousy shag._ It would help if you told us (or better yet, linked to) the dictionary where you found the definition.

Comment: I found the defination from the New Oxford Dictionary of English.

Comment: [Brit, vulgar] Slang for Sexual intercourse. They shagged in the back of the car.

Comment: I am asking for "shag"'s sex-related meaning as a noun...

Comment: I think it's mostly BrEng term. Possibly it started off as a verb, to shag someone, and then from there it progressed to describe the performance of a man or woman in bed. As Bradd Szonye pointed out, you wouldn't normally say "he is/was a shag" but rather "He's good for a shag ---> He's a good shag"

Comment: Yeah, Mari-Lou's correct.  The "of a specified ability" simply means that it tends to be used with an adjective in front (or a qualifying phrase behind).  You might say "X is a good lover." or "X is a bad lover." or "X is a lover of great skill and tenderness." but "X is a lover." by itself seems to have no meaning at at all.

Comment: I've also heard “shag my wick” as slang for a man having sex. Don't know whether that's part of the etymology or just a clever turn of phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Shag* as a noun as defined in your question is not used without qualification. You could say:

> She was a great shag, goes like the clappers.

Or

> He was a crap shag, too much teeth.

But not

> *They were a shag.

A word with similar usage patterns is [*lay*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lay#lay__29). In fact the definition is the same.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention the same thing about _lay._ I think _lay_ is predominately US and _shag_ UK.